# Bash replace the right part of a filename

Tags: linux, bash, sed, file-rename

I have trouble for renaming filename in bash.

My filename pattern is like this:

"sometext pattern trashtext.ext"

I want to keep sometext and replace pattern and trashtext by something else.
The sometext has variable length and may be containing space, the pattern is unique, and trashtext has variable length and may contain special char like '[' which are note handled well with sed.
"sometext pattern trashtext.ext" => "sometext myreplacement"

I have found a solution but I suppose there's a better way:
Get rid of the special char in trashtext:

```
rename 'y/\[/ /' *.ext
```

Get the part to remove:

```
var=$(ls | grep -Po 'pattern[^/]+')
```

Remove it with sed:

```
sed "s/$var/blabla/"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
pattern=somepattern
replacement=somereplacement
ext=ext
rename "s/$pattern.*?\.$ext$/$replacement.$ext/" *.$ext
```

The `.*?` should match your "trashtext" in between the pattern and the extension, and replace it with the replacement. It doesn't matter if trashtext contains special characters.

If, as the replacement you want to use whatever was matched by the pattern, you can do like this:

```
rename "s/($pattern).*?\.$ext$/\$1.$ext/" *.$ext
```

Finally, it's best to use the `-n` flag while playing with the syntax. This way the command will just show what it would do instead of really doing it:

```
rename -n "s/($pattern).*?\.$ext$/\$1.$ext/" *.$ext
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! Do you know where I can find more information for the rename command ? The man page doesn't say a lot of information about the special command like .*? !

Comment: @user3421248 the replacement command is a perl expression. You can read about it in the perl documentation: `man perlre`.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
f="sometext pattern trashtext.ext"
prefix=${f%% pattern*}
ext=${f##*.}
echo $prefix.$ext
```

```
sometext.ext
```